# How to allow iframe content to determine the height of a CSS Grid Item

Tags: css, iframe, css-grid

First of all, I have full access to the iframe content as well as the parent page. But I have ran into a challenge in trying to figure out why the content of my iframe is not determining the full height of my CSS Grid item.

The best thing I have found to do is apply...

```css
 iframe {
   border: solid 0.125rem pink;
   grid-area: iframe;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

Although that does get the full width of my iframe to be 100%, it has 0 impact on height adjustments.

#### My HTML

```html
<body class="iframeTest">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <aside id="sidebar">
      <div class="container">
        <p>fixed height sidebar</p>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <div id="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="section01" class="child">
          <h1>Section 01</h1>
          <p>sub content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section02" class="child">
          <h1>Section 02</h1>
          <p>sub content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section03" class="child">
          <h1>Section 03</h1>
          <p>sub content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section04" class="child">
          <h1>Section 04</h1>
          <p>sub content</p>
          <iframe src="https://..." width="640" height="384" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no">Loading…</iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="section05" class="child">
          <h1>Section 05</h1>
          <p>sub content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section06" class="child">
          <h1>Section 06</h1>
          <p>sub content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

#### My SCSS

```css
body {
  &.iframeTest {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #444;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;

    #wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;

      #sidebar {
        width: 25%;
        padding: 1.875rem;

        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        border: solid 0.125rem white;

        .container {
          display: grid;
          gap: 0;
          grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
        }
      }

      #main {
        margin-left: 23%;
        border: solid 0.125rem white;

        .container {
          display: grid;
          gap: 0;
          grid-template-rows: minmax(35.938rem, auto);

          #section01 {
            display: grid;
            place-content: center;
            padding: 1.5rem;
            background-color: rgba(255, 20, 147, 0.5);
          }

          #section04 {

            /* WHAT WOULD BE RECOMMENED HERE TO ALLOW 
               THE HEIGHT OF THE CHILD IFRAME, TO DETERMINE 
               THE HEIGHT OF THIS GRID ITEM?
            */

            iframe {
              border: solid 0.125rem pink;
              grid-area: iframe;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a full working example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kensleylewis/pen/JjxGXqX).

As you can see in my CodePen example, the iframe height is cut off, and Section 05 is overlapping it. 2 negatives.

What must I do to allow my iframe **content height** determine the height of my CSS Grid item in that area (#Section04) ?

Is there anything I can try?

Comment: To my knowledge, even for same-origin scenarios, `<iframe>` elements cannot have an auto-size or behave as you're expecting, _except_ if you use JS to measure the inner page's height _after_ it's fully loaded, then updated the outer iframe height. ([The `<iframe seamless>` attribute was supposed to enable this, but no browser ever supported it](https://caniuse.com/iframe-seamless) - excepting Chrome in 2012-2013)

Comment: I appreciate that.  then in cases like this, how would we adjust css grid item heights at various media query points?  is that even a thing?

Comment: That depends on what you think `iframe { height: 100%; }` does - or what `height: 100%;` is supposed to mean inside a `grid` formatting context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you style an iframe (or any element) with `height: 100%`, that means its height should match the height of its **containing block**. There is no way to specify that an iframe’s height should adjust automatically to fit its contents. If you want that behaviour, use a `<div>` instead of an `<iframe>`.